# How to input phone no in this 'xxx-xxx-xxxx' format in number input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want that whenever I type a number in the number input field in `XXXXXXXXXX` format it takes as `XXX-XXX-XXXX` using HTML, CSS and javascript.

Just like this snippet but without using the mask script.

```js
$('.phone_us').mask('000-000-0000');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--mask script-->

<input type="text" class="phone_us" />
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel

Comment: sorry, it is not automatically formatting like that `xxx-xxx-xxxx`.

Comment: Why you don't want to use the mask-function? If you want this feature, you have to use Javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could try like this

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {

$(".phone_us").keyup(function (e) {
    var value = $(".phone_us").val();
    if (e.key.match(/[0-9]/) == null) {
        value = value.replace(e.key, "");
        $(".phone_us").val(value);
        return;
    }

    if (value.length == 3) {
        $(".phone_us").val(value + "-")
    }
    if (value.length == 7) {
        $(".phone_us").val(value + "-")
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--mask script-->
 
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="text" maxlength="12" class="phone_us"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: it does not work properly when I write a digit alternating with a dash 1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 will give as a result 111111111111

Comment: Doesn't work if using virtual (on-screen) keyboard on mobile

Answer (score 6):

There are some working answers here, but this solution is more stable.

- Using the `oninput` event for instant replace and ...
- Applying regex on the full string, to allow copy/paste, and finally ...
- This code is shorter as well:

```js
$('.phone_us').on('input', function() {              //Using input event for instant effect
  let text=$(this).val()                             //Get the value
  text=text.replace(/\D/g,'')                        //Remove illegal characters 
  if(text.length>3) text=text.replace(/.{3}/,'$&-')  //Add hyphen at pos.4
  if(text.length>7) text=text.replace(/.{7}/,'$&-')  //Add hyphen at pos.8
  $(this).val(text);                                 //Set the new text
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="phone_us" maxlength="12">
```

Or even without jQuery:

```js
document.querySelector('.phone_us').addEventListener('input', function() { //Using input event for instant effect
  let text=this.value                                                      //Get the value
  text=text.replace(/\D/g,'')                                              //Remove illegal characters
  if(text.length>3) text=text.replace(/.{3}/,'$&-')                        //Add hyphen at pos.4
  if(text.length>7) text=text.replace(/.{7}/,'$&-')                        //Add hyphen at pos.8
  this.value=text;                                                         //Set the new text
});
```

```html
<input class="phone_us" maxlength="12">
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer, i'm deleting mine

Comment: This is the best answer, nicely done by including a js only version too

Answer (score 1):

You can implement like this

```js
  document.getElementById('txtphone').addEventListener('blur', function (e) {
        var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/);
        e.target.value = '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + '-' + x[3];
    });txtphone
```

```html
 <input type="text" class="phone_us" id="txtphone" placeholder = "(000) 000-0000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone"
       pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
       required>
```

Use HTML5 `input type=tel` to get phone number, and `pattern` attribute to specify any pattern.

`[0-9]{3}` represent the 0-9 numeric and 3 digits.
Then, add a hyphen (`-`), and use the numerics pattern again.

You can use own pattern and your country wise pattern like
`[1-9]{4}-[1-9]{6}` for the format 1234-567890.

Use the `min-length` and `max-length` in HTML5 to set limit.

Note that these patterns won't automatically add the hyphens, but will only allow correctly formatted input.

If you want get more patterns, search on web or see [HTML5pattern.com](http://html5pattern.com)

Comment: wrong answer: html5 pattern does not automatically add hyphens

Comment: i know it's not automatically add but we set pattern in HTML5 and show the pattern in placeholder then user understand normally

Answer (score -1):

Pure javascript.
Enter 10 digits in the input field and click anywhere outside the input field.

```js
var myTel = document.getElementById("tel");
myTel.addEventListener("blur", function() {
    var str=myTel.value;
    var pattern=/[0-9]{10}/;
    if (pattern.test(str)) {
        newstr=str.slice(0,3)+'-'+str.slice(3,6)+'-'+str.slice(6,10);
        myTel.value=newstr;
    }
    else {
        // bad
        myTel.value='bad value: only 10 digits';
    }
})
```

```html
<form>
   <input type="text" id="tel" name="tel" maxlength='10'>
</form>
```

Comment: this doesn't automatically add hyphens, and doesn't reject letters on input

Comment: @Mister Jojo and you did what I wrote, or do you just type in the points of everybody? Only 10 digits are allowed and are converted to the format xxx-xxx-xxxx when the blur from input is taken.

Comment: I tested all the answers, and I did not put bad points on everyone. if your answer was correct, I will not put a bad point. and I suggest you use setCustomValidity to set the error message

Comment: in the task there is the phrase "like" and not the phrase "identical." My solution does not replace data "on the fly" only after leaving the input, caused by the event blur.

Comment: It depends on whom. For copypaste probably useless. Yes, I describe the minimal solution. I think that further polemics does not make sense.

Comment: I totally agree, your answer is meaningless, especially since the use of paterns is directly attribute in html5

Comment: patterns in HTML5 does not solve the problem of replacing a string with the desired format.